# Updating Time in Local Storage

Tags: php, javascript, sql

I am trying to connect to the server every minute and pass in the variable of the current time, which would be the lastUpdate. On the server side php file, I plan to compare the passed in time variable with a `TIMESTAMP` in the database rows; much like `if (time1-time2 > certain value)...` So far the javascript code is:

```
var time;
var timer_is_on = 0;
localStorage.lastUpdate = 0;
localStorage.numUpdates = 0;

function timedCount()
{
    localStorage.lastUpdate = new Date();
    //connect to server
    contactServer(localStorage.lastUpdate);
    currentCount=currentCount+1;
    time=setTimeout("timedCount()",60000);
}
```

My question is whether I am doing this correctly. I am declaring `localStorage.lastUpdate` as `new Date()` and I'm not sure whether this is correct? I have tried the loop and every minute `lastUpdate` seems to be the same date and time.

My last question is whether I can actually compare the two time formats from javascript and php. In the SQL timestamp, the format is `2012-03-20 11:14:40` while the date format from the javascript `new Date()` is `Tue Mar 20 2012 12:32:44 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`.

Any information would be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Be careful when you use time. Your server time may be different from your client time. The best for you is to store the date of the last request in $_SESSION['last'].
With this solution, all your problems are not anymore. Your PHP set the date, so it is the same reference, and it's in a good format.

Just keep your timeout on the client side:-)

Comment: I agree. You shouldn't count on doing any comparison of the time supplied by the client with the time on the server. They could vary quite a bit, especially when you consider the effect of time zones. In general I have found it easiest to pass around times/dates using UNIX timestamps set to UTC. It is a reliable lowest common denominator on any platform.

Comment: But still, you need to avoid this when it's possible. One can't rely on what the client send to the server. Never!

Answer (score 0):

Use `new Date().getTime()` to return a UNIX timestamp; that is, the number of seconds since Jan 1st, 1970.  This makes it much easier to compare with other times.

```
localStorage.lastUpdate = new Date().getTime();
```

Will return something like this: 1332266002.

The PHP equivalent is simply `time()`.

And to convert that UNIX timestmap into a MySQL `TIMESTAMP`, use MySQL's [`FROM_UNIXTIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function.